# Typeorm oneToOne relation

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Hi i have a relation between 'rooms' and 'room-servers'

**RoomServers:**

```
@Entity({ name: 'room-servers' })
export class RoomServer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

**Rooms:**

```
@Entity({ name: 'rooms' })
export class Room {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  description: string;


  @Column({ default: 'New' })
  status: string;

  @OneToOne(() => RoomServer, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn()
  roomServer: RoomServer;
}
```

When i type sql query

```
select * from "room-servers" rm left join rooms r on rm.id = r."roomServerId";
```

It returns results (3 servers that i have in database)

But when i try to use queryBuilder to see results:

```
    const freeSocketServers = await this.roomServerRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('room-servers')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('room-servers.id', 'roomServerId')
      .getMany();

    console.log('freeSocketServer', freeSocketServers);
```

It returns nothing and i can't see console.log, it breaks on .leftJoinAndSelect

Answer (score 2):

You set the relation in the `room` entity, To make it work you should go from `room repository`

```
 const freeSocketServers = await this.roomRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('room')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('room.roomServer', 'room-server')
  .getMany();

console.log('freeSocketServer', freeSocketServers);
```

Or you can make it Bi-directional see [One-to-One](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/one-to-one-relations.md)